# cordova and ionic installation issue on Windows 8.1 64 bit

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have windows 8.1 64 Bit. I have installed node.js but when I run this command

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

it gives me these error.

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/-/escape-html-1.0.1
.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 185.3
1.17.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/-/colors-1.0.3.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 185.3
1.17.162:443
```

I have googled a lot but could not find a solution. What is the solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: do you behind any proxy? Have you checked with any other package?

Comment: you mean any other package of node.js?

Comment: Networking / firewall issue most likely.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The solution was to set the proxy settings

> npm config set proxy http://user:password@url:port
>
> npm config set https-proxy http://user:password@url:port